# Inconsistency in program running time measurement

Tags: c, time

I was doing simple test to measure the execution time of my program. So I wrote a simple program with 2 loops each iterates `N` times and `2N` times. I expected the second loop takes about twice as long but result is contrary when `N=1000000`.

I've tested it several times and got same result on another machine. Why does it happen?

My code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

long long sum;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    long elapsed;
    struct timeval start, end;

    i = atoi(argv[1]);
    sum = 0;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    while (i--)
        sum += i;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    elapsed = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000;
    elapsed += (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
    printf("1st loop : %ld\n", elapsed);

    i = 2 * atoi(argv[1]);
    sum = 0;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    while (i--)
        sum += i;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    elapsed= (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000;
    elapsed+= (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
    printf("2nd loop : %ld\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```

Some test results

```
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 10
1st loop : 0
2nd loop : 0
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 100
1st loop : 1
2nd loop : 1
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 1000
1st loop : 7
2nd loop : 14
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 10000
1st loop : 73
2nd loop : 146
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 100000
1st loop : 725
2nd loop : 1448
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 1000000
1st loop : 5369   <-- always greater than 2nd loop
2nd loop : 3536
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 10000000
1st loop : 20203
2nd loop : 34434
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 100000000
1st loop : 174058
2nd loop : 339812
[arch:test] $ ./a.out 1000000000
1st loop : 1709652
2nd loop : 3392287
```

Test environment
gcc 8.2.1, compile option `-O0`
same result on ubuntu or arch linux but not on windows 10 with cygwin

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just hitting the 1st or 2nd reschedule and the half running the first loop is taking the brunt of it. `gettimeofday` should be using the realtime clock, so times spent on context switches do count. When you next run 10 times more iterations, the number of context switches should be approx 10 times more, so if one half takes one more context switch than the other, it's not going to make that much of a difference on average.

I wasn't able to reproduce your results so well, but if I run the executable with `time -v` so the # of context switches is shown, then the timings of the 1st and 2nd loops are the nearest when the number of context switches is 2 (2nd context switch).

Comment: I just tested with `time -v` and it usually has 0 involuntary context switch. So there could be another reason?

Comment: @fips197: maybe voluntary context switches (`printf()` is mostly `write()` which is a blocking system call)